# How to integrate Xamarin Forms Shell into an MvvmCross setup

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I intend to use Xamarin Forms with MvvmCross.

According to their [tutorial](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tutorials/tipcalc/a-xamarin-forms-version?scroll=1800), the `App.cs` file is required to be added to the project:

```
 public class App : MvxApplication
  {
    public override void Initialize()
    {
      //Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterType<ICalculationService, CalculationService>();

      RegisterAppStart<MainViewModel>();
    }
  }
```

Then the original `App.xaml.cs` can be used as the `MvxFormsApplication` class:

```
public partial class FormsApp : MvxFormsApplication
{
  public FormsApp()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    //DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
    MainPage = new AppShell();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately the `AppShell.xaml` and `AppShell.xaml.cs` files add a lot of necessary UI setup code and it was originally added by the `App.xaml.cs`:

```
 MainPage = new AppShell();
```

**As MvvmCross takes over the entire initialization, I don't know how to integrate the flyout and other basic UI code.**

If I put them inside the main view like this:

```
<views:MvxContentPage.Content>
  <FlyoutItem Title="About" Icon="icon_about.png">
    <ShellContent Route="AboutPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
  </FlyoutItem>
```

I get some hiearchy error:

> Content does not support values of type 'FlyoutItem'

So how should I integrate the Shell into the MvvmCross app?

Comment: Seems not supported. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3778

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MvvmCross` does not support `Xamarin.forms.Shell` as of now.

For more information, check the [related issue](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3778) at their GitHub repository.

Comment: This post could've worked as a comment, right?

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar It looks like an answer to me. A negative (telling someone something is not possible) is still an answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel hmm acknowledged, but I thought if op is not providing any alternative solution as answer this could've fit as a comment.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar Well, there is no alternative solution for this question. It's the truth that it does not support so far.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar The absence of a workaround does not make this a comment, it is still an answer. If you think something is a bad answer, the correct 'response' is to downvote. Comments are for asking for clarification, suggesting improvements to the question (or answer) or tangential observations. See also [Is “this is not possible” an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Okay cool with that, I was just confirming.